# How does the “Module: CLI (argparse)” template in Pydev get variable replacement?

Tags: pydev

The template has these variables:

## !/usr/bin/env python3

## encoding: utf-8

'''
${module} -- ${shortdesc}

${module} is a ${description}

It defines ${classes_and_methods}

@author:     ${user_name}

@copyright:  ${year} ${organization_name}. All rights reserved.

@license:    ${license}

@contact:    ${user_email}
@deffield    updated: Updated

Where are they defined? Is there a wiki on how the template is deployed with proper information?

I assumed it would be in Project-based variables but that does not see to affect substitution.

${module} and ${year} are defined but the others are not.

Comment: While I understand the location of the pytemplate_default.py, I don't understand how to create a new one. The examples file doesn't really have good documentation on how to create one. For instance if I wanted to get the Git username and email as variables?

Answer (score 0):

The available variables are either hard-coded, provided through jython scripting or simply placeholders for the variable.

Hard-coded may be found at:

https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/blob/master/plugins/org.python.pydev/src/org/python/pydev/editor/templates/PyContextType.java

and the ones from Jython come from:

https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/blob/master/plugins/org.python.pydev.jython/jysrc/pytemplate_defaults.py

(note that you may create your own templates and specify the path to those in the preferences > pydev > scripting pydev).